# Connecting user to database with username and password

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to make little app which connect to my database after authorization.
I make my database, configure ASP.NET make new users etc. then I follow by [that](http://www.kotancode.com/2010/08/06/aspnet-authentication-wp7/) but at moment I should get link to HelloService error

```
> "Error  1  'HelloService.HelloService' does not implement interface member'HelloService.IHelloService.GetDataUsingDataContract(HelloService.CompositeType)"
```

I'm just starting with database and WP and I'm little confused. Could You help me?

Answer (score 0):

this error happened because you do not implement GetDataUsingDataContract() which is declare in your interface and isn't implement in "HelloService".

Hope it will help